# Me salen muchos errores y me abre un archivo con nombre iostream en el cual también hay errores

Tags: c++, dev-c++, librería

Hola al momento de ejecutar me abre un archivo llamado iostream en el cual también hay una cantidad de errores, ya he reinstalado varias veces el programa pero me sale siempre ese poco de errores.
Les agradecería muchísimo su ayuda, gracias.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    
    cout<<"Hola mundo";
    
return 0;
}
```

[image: Imagen del codigo]

[image: Imagen del archivo que abre]

Comment: Usar un IDE que tendrá lo menos 15 años, el cual viene con un compilador igual de antiguo puede ser un motivo. Por favor, no uses dev-cpp. No es un programa que esté preparado de forma nativa para funcionar correctamente en los Sistemas Operativos modernos

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, cual IDE me recomendarías?

Comment: tienes varios a tu disposición. En cualquier caso tendrás que aprender a manejar el nuevo IDE. La casi única ventaja que tenía dev es que sun configuración era mínima. Puedes probar con codeblocks o con qtcreator. Este último te obliga a bajarte qt, pero es bastante completo y facil de usar

Comment: Estuve probando el qt creator y al momento de ejecutar el código no me abre la consola que me abría en dev c++, sabes que puedo hacer en ese caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se debe al compilador que usas, Dev-C++ se daña muy fácilmente y a veces pierde los archivos relacionados con las librerías. Te puede llegar a ocasionar daños en tu sistema operativo, ya que cuando se han hecho demasiadas compilaciones corrompe archivos nativos del sistema.

Tienes varias soluciones:

1. Reinstalar Dev-C++, lo cual no te aconsejo porque a largo plazo te seguirá
   ocasionando los mismos problemas y pasarás la mayor parte de tu tiempo
   reinstalando el programa en vez de poder programar.
2. Instalar Code::Blocks. Es un muy buen compilador, de hecho trae muchas más
   funciones que Dev-C++. Llevo usándolo unos meses y no me ha dado ningún tipo
   de problema. puedes descargarlo desde el siguiente link:

   ```
           http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26
   ```

   Si tienes Windows 10,8,7,xp o Vista descarga el archivo que dice:

   ```
          codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe
   ```

   ese es el que viene completo. La instalación es muy sencilla.

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar en este mismo instante, pero tengo otra pregunta en dev c++ le daba en compilar y ejecutar y me habría una consola para probar el programa , lo que quería preguntarte es que si en codeblocks seria lo mismo?

Comment: Si, es exactamente lo mismo, te sale la misma consola de pantalla negra al compilar y ejecutar.

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, por favor márcala con el check como la correcta. :)

Comment: Acabo de instalarlo y te agradezco de verdad, la proxima semana tenia examenes de la universidad y me acabas de salvar, ¡Gracias!

Comment: Te funciono reinstalarlo ? @josealbertochaparrocastro

Comment: @Jorgesys Muchas veces cuando se reinstala Dev-C++ ya queda dañado, se puede solucionar situando los archivos de la instalación en una carpeta diferente a "Program Files", puede ser en "Mis Documentos"....etc, pero aún así volverá a dañarse el programa. No es recomendable estarlo reinstalando demasiadas veces, te puede ocasionar daños en tu sistema operativo, y más si es Windows 10, ya que no está adaptado para nuevos sistemas operativos. Además, es un compilador viejo que ya no tiene actualizaciones, te recomiendo usar Code::Blocks o Visual Studio Code que también son compiladores para C++.

Comment: @Jorgesys Lo reinstale varias veces y se solucionaba mientras abría el programa por primera vez y trabajaba en el pero luego al cerrarlo volvía y se dañaba.

Comment: @May395 Intente tambien cambiando el directorio de instalacion pero se dañaba y me aparecia lo mismo, me quedo por ahora con Code::Blocks gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda. Con respecto a Visual Studio Code he trabajado con el y me encanta, trate de configurarlo para trabajar en C++ pero se me hizo demasiado complicado y no pude hacerlo.

Comment: @josealbertochaparrocastro Eso mismo ya me había pasado con Dev-C++, y para el caso del Visual Studio Code a veces es muy complicado configurarlo, y el principal problema es que no puedes ingresar datos por consola. Encontré una forma de hacerlo en el siguiente link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77v-Poud_io por si prefieres usar Visual Studio Code, funciona, pero yo en lo personal preferí quedarme con Code::Blocks, espero que no de problemas con el tiempo. :)